# Retrieve only images from a website

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to retrieve all the images(nothing else) from any website say google.com programatically.Please note my objective is not to load any website in uiWebView.

Please suggest.

Comment: without knowing the values of the images. How do you think that, we can get it

Comment: that is what i asked @KumarKl

Comment: Look at here **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861674/ios-nsxmlparsing-unformed-html** and This **http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios**

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ask for all solution, show your work and ask particular solution. Any way check this https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser. Download a html page and get only  tag.

Answer (score 0):

From your ios app,Call a **php file in your server** which uses curl to get all images from a website .Then return url's to those images in your php file which will be used by your ios app.

Comment: Read the OP requirement properly. The problem says need to get the images of **any websites**.

Comment: @KumarKl yes, there are many different ways by which you can get image links from any website, i dont know much about sandbox or something, but its possible in php. what do you mean exactly kumar ?